# Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty}M^n$ for the diagonal matrix $M$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We have the matrix:
$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0.8&0&0\\
0&1.2&0\\
0&0&1\\\end{array}\right]$$
Finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are easy. But finding ${\bf M}^n$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$ is the hard part. Any suggestions?

Comment: What about using latex?

Comment: Are you able to explicity write down what $M^{n}$ is for a single $n$?  I feel like this much at least should be easy.  The problem I think you'll find is that the limit exist if you insist that all the entries be real (or complex) numbers...

Answer (score 4):

Since $\bf M$ is diagonal you can compute ${\bf M}^n$ by raising the diagonal entries to the $n$-th power. $0.8^n \to 0$, $1^n \to 1$, but $1.2^n \to \infty$, so ${\bf M}^n$ has no limit.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast reply. but how would i compute let's say M^2.  Are there any video-tutorials or such?

Comment: @rufaelJ.O Like I told you: You compute ${\bf M}^n$ by raising the diagonal entries to the $n$-th power. In your case $n=2$.

Comment: Again thank you for helping me. But how would the steady state vector look like?

Comment: @rufaelJ.O Do you know how to multiply two matrices?  You compute $M^2$ by multiplying $M$ and $M$, naturally.  Once you do that you'll see a pattern start to emerge.

Comment: I do beilive I have not stated my problem well enough. This is my task:We are interested in what happens to the system when we repeat the stepwise process several times. To get an idea of the development of th system we compute some powers of M.
 Compute M2, M3, M4 and M5. What can you say about M^n when n→ ∞ in this case?

Comment: @rufaelJ.O What I pointed out in my answer. One value will approach $0$, the other value will stay $1$ and the third value will become arbitrary large.